# Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am facing a weird error, my code is clean and everything is good, but still I got this error. Please help

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  `Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 255`
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
> Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory.
> > Could not create service of type KotlinDslWorkspaceProvider using GradleUserHomeServices.createKotlinDslWorkspaceProvider().
> > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 28s

> flutter run
> Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
> Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode..